# How to set name and binding of a port in Spyne?

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, spyne

I have written a `Spyne` web service via `Django`. I'm simulating some application, so I need to implement exact interfaces. I have following `port` definition in the original application:

```
< wsdl:service name = "SendSmsWebServiceImplService" >
  < wsdl:port binding = "tns:SendSmsWebServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name = "SendSmsWebServiceImplPort" >
      < soap:address location = "http://192.168.100.31:8181/smsgateway/sendsms" / >
  < / wsdl:port >
< / wsdl:service >
```

And this is what I have in the simulator:

```
< wsdl:service name = "SendSmsWebServiceImplService" >
  < wsdl:port name = "SendSmsWebService" binding = "tns:SendSmsWebService" >
      < soap:address location = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/smsgateway/services/SendSms/" / >
  < / wsdl:port >
< / wsdl:service >
```

I'm trying to set `name` and `binding` for the `port`. I'm using module `spyne.application.Application` to implement main application. What is the way to set these properties?

Answer (score 1):

To change the name of port and binding, you can set the "name" attribute of the Application class like the following :

```
   app = Application(services=[YourService],
      name='serviceName',
      tns='your.tns',
      in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
      out_protocol=Soap11()
   )
```

but be aware that if you have more than one service exposed  in the "services" param spyne will assign them all the same port/binding name.
This can cause problems if you try to consume the service with axis.

If this is your case, you will probably need more instances of the spyne.application.Application class.

There is another way to rename these properties. You just need to save the wsdl as xml file, rename all the properties you want and then publish the xml at your web server in place of the generated wsdl.
Feeding this xml file (with complete url) to your web service client should work just fine.

Hope it helps.